# How to Clear/Remove an ActiveDirectory property with ExtensionSet

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm using the [Principal Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384372(v=VS.90).aspx) for a User in AD to access properties not normally retrieved by the UserPrincipal. My custom properties are defined like such:

```
    [DirectoryProperty("facsimileTelephoneNumber")]
    public string FaxNumber
    {
        get
        {
            if (ExtensionGet("facsimileTelephoneNumber").Length != 1)
                return null;
            return (string)ExtensionGet("facsimileTelephoneNumber")[0];
        }
        set
        {
            ExtensionSet("facsimileTelephoneNumber", value);
        }
    }
```

How do you clear the property with ExtensionSet? If I input null or empty string, I will almost always get this error message: "The attribute syntax specified to the directory service is invalid.". It sounds like you should clear the property but I'm unsure how this works with ExtensionSet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I was not sending back an array, I was only sending back the value, not an array:

```
[DirectoryProperty("facsimileTelephoneNumber")]
    public string FaxNumber
    {
        get
        {
            if (ExtensionGet("facsimileTelephoneNumber").Length != 1)
                return null;
            return (string)ExtensionGet("facsimileTelephoneNumber")[0];
        }
        set
        {
            ExtensionSet("facsimileTelephoneNumber", string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? new string[1] {null} : new string[1] {value});
        }
    }
```